# ¿Cómo corregir este error en subscribe al usar Producto[]?

Tags: angular

Hola amigos estoy teniendo un error con el subscribe .El problema es que el subscribe no me permite poner el Producto[] xq me tira error

```
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    
    import { Producto } from '../interfaces/producto.interface';
    
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    
    })
    
    export class ProductosService {
    
      cargando = true;
      productos: Producto[] = [];
    
    
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    
        this.cargarProductos();
      }
    
      private cargarProductos() {
    
        this.http.get('https://angular-html-75495-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/productos_idx.json')
          .subscribe( ( resp:  Producto[] )  => {

            console.log(resp);
            this.productos = resp;
            this.cargando = false;
    
          });
      }
    
    
      getProducto( id: string ){
    
        return this.http.get( `https://angular-html-75495-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/productos/${ id }.json` );
      }
    
    }
```

los errores que me tira son:

```
(alias) interface Producto

import Producto

No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(observer?: Partial<Observer<Object>> | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Type '(resp: Producto[]) => void' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<Observer<Object>>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(next: (value: Object) => void): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(resp: Producto[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'resp' and 'value' are incompatible.
        The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
          Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Producto[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(next?: ((value: Object) => void) | null | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | null | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | null | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(resp: Producto[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'resp' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'Producto[]'.
          The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?ts(2769)
```

Comment: ¿Qué error tira?

Comment: Hola buenas! Me tira varios

Comment: Borra todos estos comentarios y agregalos al post original, de favor.

Comment: Ahí esta disculpas

Answer (score 0):

Como buena práctica no deberías estar suscribiéndote en el mismo servicio (Si necesitas hacer algo con la respuesta antes de suscribirte utiliza un [pipe()](https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators) y los controladores RXJS que necesites) Tu función debería regresar un Observable al cual te puedas suscribir desde otra parte del código. Pero tendrás tus motivos, considero que parte del problema es tu tipado de variables y funciones, intenta resolverlo así

```
private cargarProductos(): void {
    
        this.http.get<Observable<Producto[]>>('https://angular-html-75495-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/productos_idx.json')
          .subscribe( ( resp:  Producto[] )  => {

            console.log(resp);
            this.productos = resp;
            this.cargando = false;
    
          });
      }
```

Comment: sigue marcando error pero gracias